# Delete drawing path

Tags: android, path, draw, erase

Welcome guys,
I'm creating my drawing app using this code:

```
public class DrawingPanel extends View implements OnTouchListener {

        private Canvas mCanvas;
        private Path mPath;
        private Paint mPaint, circlePaint, outercirclePaint;

        // private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
        private float xleft, xright, xtop, xbottom;

        public DrawingPanel(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

            this.setOnTouchListener(this);

            init();

        }

        public void delete() {
            paths.remove(paths.size() - 1);
            invalidate();
        }

        public void init() {
            circlePaint = new Paint();
            mPaint = new Paint();
            outercirclePaint = new Paint();
            outercirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            outercirclePaint.setColor(0x44FFFFFF);
            circlePaint.setColor(0xAADD5522);
            outercirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
            outercirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
            mCanvas = new Canvas();
            mPath = new Path();
            paths.add(mPath);

        }

        public void colorChanged(int color) {
            mPaint.setColor(color);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            for (Path p : paths) {
                canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);

            }

        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }

        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

            RectF rectF = new RectF();

            mPath.computeBounds(rectF, true);
            if(!rectF.isEmpty()){
                Log.d("Here", "Empty");
            }

            regions.add(rectF);

            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath = new Path();
            paths.add(mPath);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            invalidate();
            if (!isErasing) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < regions.size(); i++) {
                    if (regions.get(i).contains((int) x, (int) y)) {
                        Log.d("Here", "Here");

                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Now I can really undo and redo 
I wanted to be able to delete and touch path (Yes the whole path like Samsung write on screen app) 
For this reason I tried as shown above the RectF and contains but from what I can tell the RectF selects rectangle which contains the path (it doesn't contain the path's region only but if it's curved the RectF will contain the path and the area around it), I tried regions too.

I couldn't get the only touched path in erasing mode to remove it

So any suggestions will be appreciated :)

Comment: I think there a solution especially there are a lot of apps like this in market :(